# OpenCV: Best method to track a rectangle

Tags: opencv

I've used opencv to detect humanoid blobs from mounted cameras. My code basically finds large contours, puts boxes around them and merges the intersecting boxes.
I'd now like to be able to track those boxes across the screen and hopefully get an estimation of the box speed.

Could anyone tell me how to link the box from the first frame with the one in the second? If I could do that, I'm sure I could figure the rest out.

Comment: opencv 3 has a TLD Tracking implementation

Comment: THANK YOU. THAT'S EXACTLY THE CLUE I NEEDED.

Answer (score 2):

As Micka said, OpenCV 3 has a TLD (Tracking Learning Detection) tracker. 
http://answers.opencv.org/question/52872/how-to-perform-tld-tracking-on-roi-bounding-box-using-opencv-c-builtin-methods/

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/tracking/doc/tracker_algorithms.html#tld